# Running DLL on Microsoft Azure App Services

Tags: azure, server, isapi

I am trying to migrate over an IiS website which ran as a DLL using ISAPI.

I have tried to find some form of option so that the DLL can run in Azure as a Web App Service but no luck so far.

Does anyone have any advice on how I can achieve this? The DLL obviously needs executable permissions  but so far all I have achieved is that the DLL downloads.

Thanks for you help

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it should be possible to run ISAPI in Azure AppService. 
I found this [thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/5500a826-a4bd-46e1-a9dd-8f6126c27adc/isapi-on-azure?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview) in the Microsoft forums and seems to provide the needed information.

Comment: Thanks for replying, I too found this thread however it seems the solution is incomplete. In what way should the DLL be registered in the web config file? What code should be in the applicationhost.config file? What am I missing?